# Unified naming scheme issue: SQL column names and PHP array keys casing schemes conflict

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, key

I've been scratching my head about this issue for a few days during my downtime. I am not really close to a practical solution so decided to post here. I did find this post:
[PHP/MySQL naming conventions: camelCase vs under_score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863208/php-mysql-naming-conventions-camelcase-vs-under-score) but the answers do not provide a way forwards, despite being quite informative about whys and wherefores. Please forgive me if its bad etiquette to repost a similar question, and understand that this question is specifically regarding array indexes.

So Im trying to devise a reasonably well unified naming/casing scheme accross PHP, SQL and JS, for a team of developers to conform to, so that we may all live happily in unison. Object oriented PHP is typically written using a mixture of camelCase and PascalCase, in regards to things that are not already natively named. So I am thinking of making it canonical to use camelCase and Pascal case for everything in PHP (that is not navively named). This would include classes, objects, methods, variable names, and most notably, associative array key names. However, I find myself confronted with this: SQL column names are conventionally (and for good technical reasons, as I understand it) named using snake_case.

Now, what happens when we fetch a record set?

```
$records = DB::fetchAll('SELECT * FROM reco_user');
echo $records[0]['user_name'];
echo $records[0]['date_registered'];
```

The proverbial playing field is jagged and random! We have snake_cased array keys that do not conform to our camelCase array keys scheme.

I had considered adapting my scheme to use camelCase for variable names and snake_case for the keys, but I would prefer if they did not oppose each other, as there are times when variable names and index names are used to inform one another.

I was thinking about creating a function to convert all array keys to camelCase. However, I am worried this might be considered 'overkill', and that other developers would not always use it. Im also worried that this would slow down the site (for large queries in particular), as each query would have this additional array key conversion operation.

This is a bit of a pain, because I think that camelCase would work great for everything else in PHP, everything in JS, and everything in CSS. Its just this aspect of returning SQL records thats causing the scheme from being so close yet so far.

Please let me know your thoughts. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it a big deal that SQL column names are snake cased and other array keys are camel cased? Because they look different? They represent different kinds of objects with their own conventions and these differences are supposed to help you detect [code smells](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html). So when I come across...

```
$user->name = $row['user_name'];
```

... I know that I'm more than likely seeing data from a database being assigned to an object so if there's something breaking on that line, my first instinct should be to confirm that `$row` is an array coming from the database. Now if I see...

```
$user->name = $data['userName'];
```

... it implies that somewhere, an object is populating that data so I need to start looking in a different place in the code to figure out where the data is being set. Yes, ultimately it's just ASCII text parsed by a compiler so you can name things whatever you want and use any casing you want, then debug your way to figure out the source of the data, but sticking to these conventions is supposed to help a new developer navigate an unfamiliar codebase more easily.

If you mandate all casing to be identical, you're actually making it more difficult to navigate the code and easier to forget the flow of data and logic in the app without all those differently cased reminders.